# Is there an unpublished/unfinished manuscript of Twilight by Stephenie Meyer from Edward's POV?

Tags: twilight

The published Twilight books by Stephenie Meyer are all written from Bella's point of view, although not as first person POV.

I got my hands on a manuscript pdf (unfinished; it had only about 6-7 chapters) of Twilight (1st book) which was written from Edward's point of view. The incidents in this manuscript are same as in the official published book, the only difference being how Edward sees the situations.

So, did I just read a fan fiction or has Stephenie Meyer written this manuscript (possibly unpublished or unfinished)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes; it's called *Midnight Sun*. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Sun_%28novel%29):

> Midnight Sun is an unreleased companion novel to the book *Twilight* by author Stephenie Meyer. The work retells the events of *Twilight*, but is written from the perspective of Edward Cullen instead of that of the series' usual narrating character Bella Swan. Meyer stated that Twilight was to be the only book from the series that she planned to rewrite from Edward's perspective.

It was leaked on the internet prior to completion, which pissed Meyer off so much that she didn't finish writing it:

> On August 28, 2008, Meyer halted the writing of *Midnight Sun* in response to the leak of twelve chapters of the unfinished manuscript on the Internet. She stated, "If I tried to write *Midnight Sun* now, in my current frame of mind, James would probably win and all the Cullens would die, which wouldn't dovetail too well with the original story. In any case, I feel too sad about what has happened to continue working on *Midnight Sun*, and so it is on hold indefinitely." She made the twelve-chaptered draft available on her website in fairness to her readers, now that the novel has been compromised before its intended publication date. Meyer also stated that she doesn't believe the manuscript was leaked with any malicious intent, and would not give any names.

**Update five years later:** [*Midnight Sun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Sun_(Meyer_novel)) was published on 4 August 2020.

Answer (score 1):

The partial draft of "Midnight Sun" is posted on Stephenie Meyer's website http://stepheniemeyer.com/pdf/midnightsun_partial_draft4.pdf . It contains the first 12 chapters of "Twilight", retold from Edward's POV.

Comment: Perhaps just edit the link into @randal'Thor 's answer?

Comment: It's such a shame she didn't want to finish, and such a shame that people leaked it. I'm reading it now, I found it yesterday on my own, and I would like to be able to read how it was when Bella got bitten by James.